# Syntax error: Missing operand before 'And' operator

Tags: vb.net, filter, bindingsource

i am using vb.net 
here is my code to filter bindingsource
i get this erro Syntax error: Missing operand before 'And' operator.

```
Private Function SetFilter() As String
    Dim datee As String = String.Format("datee >= #{0:M/dd/yyyy}# AND datee <= #{1:M/dd/yyyy}#", _
                              DateTimePicker1.Value, _
                              DateTimePicker2.Value)
    Dim client As String = If((TextBox1.Text.Length > 0), String.Format("[client] LIKE '%{0}%'", TextBox1.Text), "")
    Dim ref As String = If((TextBox2.Text.Length > 0), String.Format("[REF] LIKE '%{0}%'", TextBox2.Text), "")

    Return String.Format("{0} AND {1} AND {2}", datee, client, ref)
End Function


Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
    SalesBindingSource.Filter = SetFilter()
End Sub

Private Sub DateTimePicker2_ValueChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker2.ValueChanged
    'error here
    SalesBindingSource.Filter = SetFilter()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    SalesBindingSource.Filter = SetFilter()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    SalesBindingSource.Filter = SetFilter()
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the content of TextBox1 and TextBox2? Do you have text with single quotes?

Comment: textbox1 to search for client                                               textbox2 to search for reference number

Comment: This query is vulnerable to a Sql Injection attack since you use string concatenation of user supplied input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to replace your filter creating method with a more secure way to handle the content of the two textboxes and the situation in which one or both textboxes are empty

```
Dim client As String = If((TextBox1.Text.Length > 0), _
             String.Format(" AND [client] LIKE '%{0}%'", TextBox1.Text.Replace("'", "''")),"")
Dim ref As String = If((TextBox2.Text.Length > 0), _
             String.Format(" AND [REF] LIKE '%{0}%'", TextBox2.Text.Replace("'", "''"), "")

Return String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", datee, client, ref)
```

The replace call double a single quote inserted by your user in the textbox, the AND is directly inserted in the string for client and for ref, otherwise you get an invalid sql if one or both textboxes are empty